# Are there hardware restrictions for the Nokia Imaging SDK?

Tags: windows-phone-8, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

Does anyone know if the Nokia Imaging SDK is limited / restricted to Nokia hardware?  In other words, if I use the SDK to create a Windows Phone 8 app, will the app run on an HTC or Samsung device?

I'm not seeing any specific verbiage on the [Nokia Developer](http://developer.nokia.com/) site that mentions hardware / hardware partner restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no hardware restriction on the Imaging SDK. You can use it on any Windows Phone 8 device.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to hear!  Do you have some documentation that states this or did you find out by experimenting with different hardware?

Comment: @gannaway Unfortunately I don't have any documentation. But many apps already use the Imaging SDK, and they'll work on any WP8 device. http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Apps_that_use_the_Nokia_Imaging_SDK